# same behavior as "Starts" text/date picker in iOS/iPhone calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to learn ios development. I want to simulate the same behavior as I get when I Tap the "Starts" row in iphone calendar app

- Same row has the column name "Starts" with default value of Datepicker.date
- When I tap on the row, it expands (pushes next row down) and brings up date picker

Right now, I have a text field with its input set to date picker value.

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
[self.timeTextField setInputView:datePicker];
```

In my case date picker, comes bottom up.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your question is too broad, and too much of a "spoon-feed me a complete solution to my problem" question. You're much more likely to get help if you try specific things and ask questions about the problems you have in implementing those things.

Break it down into parts. What are the sub-parts, and what are you able to do on your own? Have you created a date picker and set it to a default date yet?

Are you looking for help with inserting a date picker as a new cell in a table view immediately below the "starts" cell? are you looking for help with making changes to the picker update the "starts" date cell immediately?

Again, break it into parts and tackle each part separately. First, simply create a date picker on it's own window and learn how to use it. Then add a label under the date picker, set yourself up as the picker's delegate, and display the date the user selects in the picker into the label.

Then figure out how to set a date picker to a specific date, and/or set the earliest/latest date the picker will accept.

Now figure out how to make a table view respond to taps on a row (try didSelectRowAtIndexPath). Then look at the animated methods for inserting a new row into a table view.

If you have trouble, post back with specific questions on the trouble you are having.